# How to convert a String value to enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums

How do I convert a String value to an enum of String type?

My enum is defined as followed:

```
enum TemplateSlotType : String {
    case Default = ""
    case Recommendation = "recommendation"
}
```

I want to convert the string "recommendation" to a type .Recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find my answer here on Stack Overflow, but did find my answer.

This will work for other enum types as well:

```
enum Lets : String {
    case X = "x"
    case Y = "y"
    case Z = "z"
}

var zz = Lets.fromRaw("z")
zz! == .Z // true
println(Lets.Y.toRaw())
```

For more info, checkout: http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/27/swift-converting-values-to-enumerations/

My final implementation:

```
if let slotType = json["type"].object as? String {
    type = TemplateSlotType(rawValue: slotType)!
}
```